# Сохранение нажатия кнопки Android

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в `onSaveInstanceState` сохранить информацию о нажатой кнопке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ламерский гайд такой (то есть готовый для copy/paste):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
   state.putString("myButton", "my button was pressed!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй android-annotation вообще не придется заморачиваться подобными проблемами.

[@InstanceState](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Save-instance-state)